# how to Storing sending email messages in django restframework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

```
def send_update(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.author_name:
        message = "Book is updated"
        subject = "Updates"
        send_mail(subject, message, your_email,
            [instance.email,])

post_save.connect(send_update, sender=Book)
```

This my "signals.py" I am sending mail, after sending mail I need to save the message and I have to use in views.py

Comment: what error are you facing?

Comment: You can define a new model for storing emails.

Comment: actually @akazuko what I am facing in my API I have to show message while sending an email I don't know how to implement?in my "views.py".

Comment: @MohammadAli already model is there in that model i have to change status for one variable while changing status i have to send email i need that email message to store one variable.

Comment: can you provide more information regarding "show message" ?

Comment: @akazuko - there is a one filed contains dropdown values if I changed the dropdown values means I m sending an email by using signals.py I want to store what is the email Il sending I need to stored in backend database.

Comment: If it is coupled with user and you want to retain only the latest one, then you can store the same in user document. Else, recommended way would be to have a separate email table where you can send the information regarding the content of email + recipient(user).

Comment: @akazuko did u have any sample code? or reference?